# VS 2013 Express not allowing start up Scripts in SQL Server Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was following a Tutorial which is using VS 2013, and for me the option Startup script in ProjectSettings -> Debug is greyed out. I am using VS 2013 Express, so is that a limitation for Express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes seems to be limited, now I'm using VS2015 and it is there.